# Grub messed up on dual boot machine - can't boot live usb

Tags: grub2

I have a laptop on which I had Win 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed. The hdd has two partitions (one primary and one extended). Grub wasn't loaing initially so I ran  the boot disk repair tool which seemed to sort it out. However, I mistakenly removed python (long story) from the Ubuntu OS and this obviously messed up Ubuntu a lot. So I decided to reintsall both Win7 and Ubuntu 12.04 in an attempt to get things back fresh. Win 7 went fine, but now when I try and use the Live USB to install Ubuntu I get:

> error: no such device:
>
> grub rescue >

I guess grub is still there despite the Win 7 reinstall and it can't find the partition for Ubuntu (which I deleted prior to the fresh install).

I have tried fixmbr in windows console and the boot-repair-disk utility, but no joy. I cannot boot the live usb so no access to linux.

A real mess.

Any suggestions from the community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one occasion I had Ubuntu installer to mistakingly install GRUB on the flash drive instead of the HDD - the machine only booted while the flash drive was plugged in.

I would try booting to Windows and re-creating the LiveUSB to make sure you don't have GRUB installed on it by the previous install.

Comment: Amazing! That was it. Haven't heard of this issue before. Thanks very much!